# Passar um nome para arquivo baixado com <p:fileDownload>

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jasper-reports

Tenho um método que gera um relatório PDF com `Jasper` e retorna um `DefaultStreamedContent`. Chamo o método no `<p:fileDownload>` dessa forma:

```
 <p:fileDownload value="#{listarReembolsoBean.getSampleReportPDF(reembolso)}" />
```

Esse é o método:

```
public StreamedContent getSampleReportPDF(Solicitacao rel) {
        InputStream relatorio = null;
        Map<String, Object> filtro = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        System.out.println("Codigo solicitacao:" + rel.getCodigo());

        try {
            InputStream image = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("Report/logo-unimed-correto.png");
            filtro.put("codigo", rel.getCodigo());
            filtro.put("image", image);
            String pdfFile = "C:\\sampleReport.pdf";

            ByteArrayOutputStream Teste = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            JasperReport jasperReport = (JasperReport) JRLoader
                    .loadObject(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("Report/RelatorioReembolso.jasper"));
            jasperReport.setWhenNoDataType(WhenNoDataTypeEnum.ALL_SECTIONS_NO_DETAIL);

            Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, filtro, ConexaoMysql.abrir());
            System.out.println("Conexao aberta: " + print);

            JRExporter exporter = new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter();

//          exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, pdfFile);
            exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, Teste);
            exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, print);
            exporter.exportReport();

            relatorio = new ByteArrayInputStream(Teste.toByteArray());

        } catch (JRException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return new DefaultStreamedContent(relatorio);

    }
```

Porém quando abre a caixa de download do arquivo o nome fica como `NULL`, aonde posso setar um nome para esse arquivo?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problema resolvido, apenas alterei o `return` do método dessa forma:

```
return new DefaultStreamedContent(relatorio, "application/pdf", "RelatorioReembolsoGeral.pdf");
```